# Adding a certificate to azure VM from Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I am configuring App Service Certificate to Azure Virtual Machine using the steps on this link - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/10/26/configure-app-service-certificate-to-azure-virtual-machine/

I have done step 1 to step 6. I got stuck trying to Add the certificate to VM from key Vault. I used the steps in the link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-secure-web-server

I have used the following scripts on the cloud shell on azure portal.

```
$certUrl = (Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "xxxKeyVault" -Name "xxxcert").Id;

$vm=Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "xxx_Group" -Name "XXX"

$vaultId=(Get-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName "xxxKeyVault").ResourceId

$certStore = "MyCert";

$vm = Add-AzureRmVMSecret -VM $vm -SourceVaultId $vaultId -CertificateStore $certStore -CertificateUrl $certURL

Update-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "xxx_Group" -VM $vm>
```

But getting to the last script, I get the error

> Update-AzureRmVM : List vaultCertificates contains repeated instances of (https://xxxkeyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/xxxxxx/xxxxxx, mycert), which is disallowed.
>   ErrorCode: InvalidParameter
>   ErrorMessage: List vaultCertificates contains repeated instances of (https://xxxkeyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/xxxxxx/xxxxxx, mycert), which is disallowed.
>   ErrorTarget: vaultCertificates
>   StatusCode: 400
>   ReasonPhrase: Bad Request
>   OperationID : 51078b39-72a0-4a6f-be02-e0fff12dff8b
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Update-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "xxxx_Group" -VM $vm
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Update-AzVM], ComputeCloudException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.UpdateAzureVMCommand

Am I missing something?
My Vm a window.

UPDATE
I have verified that I have more than the same certificate on the Vm. Please, which one exactly do I remove?

```
"secrets": [
        {
          "sourceVault": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/xxxKeyVault"
          },
          "vaultCertificates": [
            {
              "certificateUrl": "https://xxxkeyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/xxxx/xxxx",
              "certificateStore": "My"
            },
            {
              "certificateUrl": "https://xxxxkeyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/xxxxx/xxxxx",
              "certificateStore": "My"
            },
            {
              "certificateUrl": "https://xxxxkeyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx",
              "certificateStore": "My"
            },
            {
              "certificateUrl": "https://xxxxkeyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx",
              "certificateStore": "MyCert"
            }
          ]
        },
         {
      "sourceVault": {},
      "vaultCertificates": {}
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a certificate to the Azure VM, you should make sure which OS type of the VM first. With the description in the Document [Secure a web server on a Windows virtual machine in Azure with SSL certificates stored in Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-secure-web-server) that you followed:

> These SSL certificates can be stored in Azure Key Vault, and allow
>   secure deployments of certificates to Windows virtual machines (VMs)
>   in Azure.

It seems that just work for Windows VM and I have also done the test. So if you want to add a certificate to the Linux VM, you can take a look at [Secure a web server on a Linux virtual machine in Azure with SSL certificates stored in Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-secure-web-server).

In addition, the error also shows:

> Update-AzureRmVM : List vaultCertificates contains repeated instances
>   of (https://xxxkeyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/xxxxxx/xxxxxx,
>   mycert), which is disallowed.

I suggest that you'd better have a check if the VM already have the same certificate. On my side, if you add the same certificate twice, and the second time will give the error like this:

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that it is a widows vm. Maybe I will check if the VM has the certificate already. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I just checked if the certificate exists already on the vm, but it is not there.

Comment: Is that true? I did the test and give the same error with adding the same certificate twice. See the answer, I have updated it.

Comment: You can use the [Azure REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/get) to get the VM info and have a check. And you can see it in the **osProfile**.

Comment: I can see the certificates now. I have over 4 of them. Thanks a lot. I will run the scripts again later today.

Comment: You're welcome. And if the answer is helpful you can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

what you need to do is this:

1. open resources.azure.com
2. navigate to your vm
3. click edit, remove the certificate from osProfile, click patch
4. rerun your script

the thing with Azure - it doesnt know (or care) if your vm actually has that certificate you are trying to install, what it complains about is the fact that VM definition already has that certificate, so it cannot add it.

Comment: I have seen more than 4 of them. Do I remove all of them or just leave one of them. Secondly if it is all, do I remove it from the "secrets" node? Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is a secrets node?

Comment: you could remove the one you are trying to add again, or you could remove all of them, its doesnt really matter, it wont remove them from the vm

Comment: Sorry I am new and don't have enough reputation to vote you up. Thanks a lot. You really helped.

Comment: this probably means you need to accept this answer instead of the other one ;)